# I uninstalled Mount & Blade: Warband, and now it's not in my Steam Library

Tags: steam

I uninstalled Mount & Blade: Warband and it said the game would be in my games library to reinstall at a later time, but the game is not there.

Does anyone know how to get the game to reinstall with out me buying the game again?

Comment: Which game was it?  Had you bought it, or was it a free weekend one or something?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to buy the game in the marketplace (don't actually buy it to test this ofc)? Does it say you already own it?

Comment: It was mount and blade warband and i brought it.

Comment: It does not say i own it even though i brought the game.

Comment: What's your username on Steam?

Comment: My username on steam is Dethcaln1

Comment: Not even coming up on a search.

Comment: Try adding me. Same username as I use here.

Comment: You added me as a completely different username. Are you definitely on the right account?

Comment: Yes... what username did i add you as?

Comment: matthew0880 though that may be a nickname

Comment: Yeah, it is a nickname I should change it.

Comment: Ok, checking Mount & Blade Warband on the store on my end tells me you don't own it. I'll post the next bit as an answer

Comment: Did you actually buy the game? Or was it a free weekend kind of deal where it was already in your library?

Comment: You can check your Buy list/History if your realy pruchased the game or not!

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, if this is the case, there's not much we can do to help you (beyond verifying what is going on). This is a matter for Steam Support.

To submit a ticket, click "Help", then "Steam Support". Once you register a Steam Support account, send a ticket to Valve and they'll look into it. Try to find a copy of the receipt you received by email when you bought the game and include it in the ticket.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, it's probably just a filter on the game library.

Comment: @Kroltan We actually discussed this in the comments, leading to me friending him and checking whether he owned it in the Steam store. He didn't. But, whatever- I'm sure brainless downvoting accomplishes just as much.

Comment: I had a similar issue with another game. It disappeared out of my library, and checking the game's store page did not show I owned it. I found the steam installed game shortcut, and ran that. The game said it needed to be installed, so I left it to do its business. Once it was done, the game ran fine, it was listed in my game library in the steam client, AND the steam store page listed it as "you already own this game". Something odd occasionally happens to uninstalled Steam games.

Comment: @StarPilot's strategy may be used here, the OP may want to create a shortcut to the following link: `steam://rungameid/48700` (48700 is M&B:W's Steam store ID), and running it may promt to install the game. Checking the purchase history would also be interesting, to confirm Steam still has your purchase recorded.

Answer (score 4):

At the top left, make sure the filter is set to "Games" and not "Installed".

[image]

Comment: Regardless of what the filter is, if he bought it and uninstalled it, it should still show up in the user's game list.

Comment: The "Installed" filter exists to let you hide the games (and other media too) that are not currently installed on your system. It only makes sense that a game that was just uninstalled would not show up in the list that is filtered to only show installed games.